# NDSolve Time-dependent Schrodinger Equation

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am currently trying to solve a time dependent Schrodinger equation (TDSE) for a rectangular potential barrier and a varying magnetic potential with a time dependent magnetic potential is oriented on the x-Axis and has a sinusoidal form.

The equation I'm trying to solve is:
$$
  i\omega\partial_{\xi}u(x,\xi) = -\frac{\hbar^2 c^2}{2\mu c^2}\partial_{x,x}u(x, \xi) + V(x)u(x,\xi) + i \frac{\hbar c}{\mu c^2}q* A0*cos(\xi)\partial_{x}u(x,\xi)
$$

$\xi = \omega t$.

The initial state of the particle is a stationary state with energy Q > 0 found by:

```
hbarc = 197.326;
mu = 4000.;
S0 = 3.0;
omega = 0.0001;
ec = 0.0854;
q = 2.*ec;
Q = 5.0;
V0 = 0.;
V1 = 20.;
a = 10.;
l = 5.;
x0 = 0.;
xN = a + l + 10.;
A0 = mu omega S0/(hbarc q);
k = Sqrt[2 mu Q]/hbarc;
potential[x_] = Piecewise[{{V1,a<=x<=a+l},{V0,x<a||x>a+l}};

eqSchUnpert={Q*u0[x]==-hbarc*hbarc/(2*mu)*D[u0[x],{x,2}]+potential[x]*u0[x]};
bc={u0[xN]==beta*Exp[I*k*xN],(D[u0[x],x]/.x->xN)==Exp[I*k*xN]*beta*I*k};
sol=ParametricNDSolve[Join[eqSchUnpert,bc],u0,{x, x0, xN},beta]
```

and, since it is not a bound state, any beta will do so I choose 10^-4:

```
psi0=u0[10.^-4]/.sol
```

Now, when adding the magnetic potential the code takes forever and doesn't bring any result:

```
eqSchPert = {I*omega*
 D[u[t, x],t]==-hbarc*hbarc/(2 mu)D[u[t, x],{x, 2}]+
 potential[x] u[t, x] + I*S0*omega*Cos[t]*D[u[t, x], x]};
```

with the initial and boundary contitions:

```
icPert = {u[0.,x]== psi0[x]};
bcPert = {u[t,x0+S0]== psi0[x0+S0 + S0*Sin[t]]*Exp[-I*Q*t/omega], u[t,xN-S0]== psi0[xN-S0 + S0*Sin[t]]*Exp[-I*Q*t/omega]};
```

NDSolve never finishes. If anyone knows what's wrong, please tell me. What I'm doing now is:

```
eqSyst=Join[eqSchPert, icPert, bcPert];

NDSolve[eqSyst,u,{t,0.,2.},{x,x0+S0,xN-S0},Method->{"MethodOfLines","SpatialDiscretization"->{"TensorProductGrid","DifferenceOrder"->"Pseudospectral","MinPoints"->300,"MaxPoints"-> 300}}]
```

**EDIT 1**

After searching a little more I gave FiniteElement a try and I think I'm getting close, but I'm not there yet. If I set $\omega$ = $10^{4}$ and solve the equation with:

```
omega = 10.^4;
icPert = {u[r, 0.] == psi0[r]};
bcPert = {u[k*(x0 + S0), t] == 
psi0[k (x0 + S0 + S0*Sin[t])]*Exp[-I*Q*t/omega],
    u[k*(xN - S0), t] == 
psi0[k (xN - S0 + S0*Sin[t])]*Exp[-I*Q*t/omega]};
schEq = {I*omega*D[u[r, t], t] == -Q (D[u[r, t], {r, 2}]) + I*k*S0*omega*Cos[t] D[u[r, t], r] + potential[r]*u[r, t]};
eqSyst = Join[schEq, icPert, bcPert];
```

and I use a mesh made like this:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
mesh = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{k (x0 + S0), 0.}, {k (xN - S0), tFinal}], "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.05, "MeshElementType" -> QuadElement];
```

the solution becomes:

```
solution = NDSolve[eqSyst, u, {r, t} \[Element] mesh];
u1 = u /. First[solution];
Plot3D[Abs[Evaluate[u1[r, t]]]^2, {r, k (x0 + S0), k (xN - S0)}, {t, 0., 2*\[Pi]}, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> All]
```

I obtain:
[image]

which is exactly what I expected for $\omega$ very small. If I try this with the previous $\omega$ I get this:

[image]

which is absurd. In both cases, I receive a warning message:

```
NDSolve::femcscd: The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help.
```

Please note that in the equations I passed to the dimensionless variable $x->\rho = k x$, with $k$ defined in the beggining of this post.

Comment: Hi Stefan and welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). [Edit](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) if improvable, show due diligence by giving a **minimal working example** of code you have tried yourself. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Definition of eqSyst ???

Comment: This is mistake `u[t,x0+S0]== psi0[x0+S0 + S0*Sin[t]]*Exp[-I*Q*t/omega]`.

Comment: Sorry, Ulrich, I just added the definition of eqSyst.

Comment: Alex Trounev, what do you mean? What's wrong?

Comment: Sorry, Stefan, this is not my opinion, this is what the Mathematica tells about these boundary conditions - not compatible with the initial conditions. The task should be simplified, get an answer, and then go to a complex case, adding new conditions step by step.

Answer (score 2):

Minimum working code, in which all equations have solutions. I made a replacement `t/omega->t` to reduce computation time.

```
hbarc = 197.326;
mu = 4000.;
S0 = 3.0;
omega = 0.0001;
ec = 0.0854;
q = 2.*ec;
Q = 5.0;
V0 = 0.;
V1 = 20.;
a = 10.;
l = 5.;
x0 = 0.;
xN = a + l + 10.;
A0 = mu omega S0/(hbarc q);
k = Sqrt[2 mu Q]/hbarc;
potential[x_] = 
  Piecewise[{{V1, a <= x <= a + l}, {V0, x < a || x > a + l}}];
eqSchUnpert = {Q*u0[x] == -hbarc*hbarc/(2*mu)*D[u0[x], {x, 2}] + 
     potential[x]*u0[x]};
bc = {u0[xN] == beta*Exp[I*k*xN], (D[u0[x], x] /. x -> xN) == 
    Exp[I*k*xN]*beta*I*k};
psi0 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eqSchUnpert, bc}, 
   u0, {x, x0, xN}, {beta}];
Plot[Abs[psi0[10^-4][x]], {x, x0, xN}]
eqSchPert = {I*
    D[u[t, x], t] == -hbarc*hbarc/(2 mu) D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] + 
    potential[x] u[t, x] + 
    I*S0*omega*Cos[t*omega]*D[u[t, x], x]}; icPert = {u[0., x] == 
   psi0[10^-4][x]};
bcPert = {u[t, x0 + S0] == psi0[10^-4][x0 + S0], 
   u[t, xN - S0] == psi0[10^-4][xN - S0]};

sol1 = NDSolveValue[{eqSchPert, icPert, bcPert}, 
   u[t, x], {t, 0., 2}, {x, x0 + S0, xN - S0}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> 300, "MaxPoints" -> 1000, 
       "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}, MaxSteps -> 10^6];
Plot3D[Abs[sol1], {t, 0, 2}, {x, x0 + S0, xN - S0}, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> Hue, AxesLabel -> {"t", "x"}]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Thank you very much! I know that NDSolve is able to find a solution for short time intervals. I want one the range $\omega$ t from 0 to 2 Pi. This is the reason I post this question. I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: I have modified the boundary condition for the second problem and now it does not give a warning for inconsistent boundary and initial conditions.

Comment: Thank you, Stefan. I made a calculation with these boundary conditions. To count for long times, we need to reduce the equation to a dimensionless form, determine the region $ 0\le x \le 2$, and  lower the omega to $2\pi / 100$. In this case, there is a chance to count up to $t=100$. I launched such a task, but it has not yet been counted to the end, but it requires fast CPU and  a memory of at least 10 GB.

Comment: Of course we can scale the problem. But it must be scaled all together: the energy of the particle needs to be 4 orders of magnitude higher than $\omega$ and so on. You can choose any system of units as long as the quantities follow the ratio in my original post.

Comment: Why do not you do it yourself? Now the task looks like a freak. It is necessary to give it a form convenient for calculation. So I could not calculate the task for t=100. The computer did not have enough memory. Although it seems that the task is simple. But the Mathematica is hanging on it.

Comment: Well I'm also trying myself. I knew that enough resources would help in finding a solution, but my goal is to find a solution using a smart idea, not a super computer. The reason for this is that this potential is rather simple and if I need 10GB of memory and 2 hours of processing time in this case, it means that for more complicated systems I will not be able to find a solution.

Comment: A strange task, it takes a lot of resources to solve it, but I do not see why these resources are needed. There is a suspicion that the computational process does not converge, it happens in the case of nonlinear problems, but here is a linear problem. And there must be a simple solution.